# Date filters not working as expected when querying Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm trying to filter the results I'm getting from the [Users/Calendar/List Events endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) of the MS Graph API. While trying to figure out what's going on I've been using the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/preview). If I make a request with a filter as follows:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{redactedUPN}/events?$filter=start/dateTime ge '2022-05-03T00:00:00.0000000Z'
```

I get back a bunch of results, one of which is this all day event (I've removed most of the response's body for clarity):

```
{            
    "subject": "Annual leave",
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2022-05-04T00:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2022-05-05T00:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    }
},
```

As you can see, this event starts at midnight (UTC) on 4th May 2022. If I now modify my request to filter for events a day later, thus:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{redactedUPN}/events?$filter=start/dateTime ge '2022-05-04T00:00:00.0000000Z'
```

This same event is not included in the results. I would expect it to be included because I'm using the `ge` predicate, meaning "greater than or equal to" according to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?view=graph-rest-1.0#filter-parameter), and my missing event's start datetime is identical to the date I've passed in my filter. Just to prove the point, if I change the predicate and use `eq` (equals) instead:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{redactedUPN}/events?$filter=start/dateTime eq '2022-05-04T00:00:00.0000000Z'
```

I get no events at all in my response. Even if I copy and paste the value from the response to the first request into the filter for the subsequent requests, the event doesn't get returned. What gives? Is this a time zone thing? I hoped that by including the `Z` in my time filter I was being specific enough (note that it doesn't work without the `Z` either).

As a side note, the documentation for the Graph API isn't great. The only way I learned to use the format `start/dateTime` to reference the nested property was by coming across it in an issue posted by a user on GitHub. I can't see it anywhere in the docs.

### Update

I've just tried another request, using the `eq` predicate and setting the time filter to an hour earlier than I'm expecting (my time zone is UTC+1), like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{redactedUPN}/events?$filter=start/dateTime eq '2022-05-03T23:00:00.0000000Z'
```

That query *does* return the event in question, although the response is the same as the one posted above, with the time showing as midnight on the 4th May and the time zone as UTC. So it definitely looks like a time zone issue, but surely if my filter matches the response's value exactly that should work?!

Comment: Are you using a Prefer Header for the OutlookTimezone ? this would affect the query even though your datetime is in UTC. If you aren't using any prefer header you could try adding Prefer:outlook.timezone="UTC" and see if that make a difference.

Comment: From what I can see in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#support-various-time-zones) that header should only change the way the dates are presented in the response, but I've tried it in any case and the event in question is still filtered out when it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR - the value of the `start/dateTime` property for all-day events will *always* be 00:00:00, regardless of time zone, but when filtering all-day events by date/time, you must either include a `Prefer` header with the appropriate time zone or specify the date/time in UTC equivalent to midnight in your time zone.

Ok, I think I've got to the bottom of this, although I'd argue that this represents a bug in the Graph API and I'll be raising an issue accordingly.

It seems that this behaviour is a peculiarity of all-day events. For regular, single-instance events which are not all-day events, the value shown in the response from the Graph API for the `start.dateTime` property is, as [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#support-various-time-zones) explain, in the format you specify in your request's `Prefer` header, defaulting to UTC if no `Prefer` header is included.

However, for all-day events, the value in the `start.dateTime` property is *always* midnight on the day of the event, regardless of what time zone is specified in the `Prefer` header. Somewhat bizarrely, if I omit the `Prefer` header, my all-day event's `start` property looks like this:

```
"start": {
    "dateTime": "2022-05-04T00:00:00.0000000",
    "timeZone": "UTC"
}
```

If I specify my time zone (`Prefer: outlook.timezone="Europe/London"`), the response is this:

```
"start": {
    "dateTime": "2022-05-04T00:00:00.0000000",
    "timeZone": "Europe/London"
}
```

Same time, different time zone, which is, at best, confusing and, I'd argue, wrong.

To make matters worse, as my attempts to filter these responses has shown, the datetime shown in the response's `start.dateTime` property isn't necessarily what's actually in the database. If I use the filter `$filter=start/dateTime eq 2022-05-04 00:00:00.0000000'` with no `Prefer` header, I get no results.

Change the filter to an hour earlier, though, and my all-day event is included in the response. That's fair enough, because an all-day event which runs from 00:00:00 - 23:59:59 in my time zone (UTC+1) is running from 23:00:00 - 22:59:59 UTC. The problem is that the response *still* shows the `start.dateTime` in the response as "2022-05-04T00:00:00.0000000".

Effectively, I'm saying "get me all events which start at exactly 23:00:00 UTC" and the response is saying, "ok, here's a result that matches your filter - it starts at 00:00:00 UTC". That makes no sense!